# Date column causing an issue while importing mongodb collection?

Tags: mongodb

I have an backup of mongodb collection in json format, that I want to import on my Mongodb atlas. While importing I am getting this error:

```
**Failed: error getting extended BSON for document #4: parsing time "-0350-01-31T11:06:32.000Z" as "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00": cannot parse "-0350-01-31T11:06:32.000Z" as "2006"**
```

In backup I have lot of entries like this:

```
{"_id":"zHnoZffrYk","ulanId":"500046807","_rperm":[],"_wperm":[],"_acl":{},"isValid":true,"numberOfUsages":0,"_updated_at":{"$date":"2020-04-23T21:10:09.866Z"},"_created_at":{"$date":"2017-07-13T10:49:13.873Z"},"description":"Greek vase painter, active ca. 340-305 BCE in Apulia","firstname":"","lastname":"Painter of the Kassel Cup","birthday":{"$date":"-0370-01-31T11:06:32.000Z"},"dateOfDeath":{"$date":"-0270-01-31T11:06:32.000Z"}}
```

As I guess ```{"$date":"-0370-01-31T11:06:32.000Z"}`` kind of values causing an issue.

Is there any way to import jsong collection with the above values..

Comment: Which date is represented? Is it the greogiran calendar or is it really 350 B.C.?

Comment: Yes, it is in BC

Comment: In case the BC date is imported, how should it look like in the MongoDB document? Take a look at how JSON date gets converted to date object during the import. There are two formats: MongoDB Extended JSON v1 and v2. By default, the conversion is expecting a v2 format JSON. But, if you can use the v1 version by specifying the --legacy option, and see if it helps. Refer the docs for details.